# How to compress viewstate

Tags: asp.net

when i click on asp buttons it is giving me error as "The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted."

on searching for this error,someone told me that viewstate is storing large amount of data.

so i want to compress the viewstate.
can anybody tell me how to compress the viewstate in asp.net project c# 3.5

Answer (score 1):

look at this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/viewstate/ViewStateCompression.aspx :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of a Compression Manager.

[This](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=67) article does a good job of showing how to create a Compression Manager to compress Viewstate.